# How to generate graph where the X axis start from right to left

Tags: matlab

I  want to display graph where the X axis start from right to left.
for example:

```
x = [1:10];
y = [1:10];
```

when I'm using `plot(x, y)` the values of x start for left corner (x=1) to right corner (x=10)
I want that the graph will start from (x=10) on the left to right corner (x=1).

Using `plot(fliplr(x),y)` gives me same results.

Comment: [This might help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31825575/4806927)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the axis `XDir` property to reverse

```
>> plot(x,y)
>> set(gca,'XDir','reverse')
```

EDIT: Didn't see this was answered in OP comments before posting ...